# Can't submit button on load event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a example to work jquery 1.7.2 and onload event to do click onload event so nobody needs to do click.

Here is my example:http://jsfiddle.net/fzTD5/32/

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){ 
document.getElementById("formButton").submit();
}
</script>
<form action="page/site" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
    <input type="submit" id="formButton" />
</form>
```

I tried

```
document.getElementById("formButton").click();
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: do you mean auto submit the form?

Comment: see this like it is work in jquery http://jsfiddle.net/fzTD5/22/

Comment: what about window onload?

Comment: if the answer helped you should accept it and then the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes: 1- form's method 'postt' and submit's invocation over a button instead a form element. Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit()
})
</script>
<form action="page/site" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
    <input type="submit" id="formButton" />
</form>
```

Edited:

If you redirect to the same page and you want to avoid an endless submit loop, try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.search.indexOf("auto_submited") == -1){
        $("#form").attr('action', $("#form").attr('action') + "?auto_submited=1")
        $("#form").submit()
    }
})

</script>
<form action="page/site" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
    <input type="submit" id="formButton" />
</form>
```

It's better to check it in server-side, even being possible with javascript

Comment: you are missing a ; buddy,

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: Are you sure @vignesh_ms ?

Comment: yeah, If i miss that ; in js it will throw error, but not sure about jquery.

Comment: ok i noticed something wrong here....when it clicks submit button will do multiple times so it will never stop the submit is there any way to stop it?

Comment: You should check if the post was an auto_submited post. Anyway, it's possible in javascript too, have a look to the last edit

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){ 
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
</script>
<form action="page/site" id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
    <input type="submit" id="formButton" />
</form>
```

jquery --

```
 <script>
    document.ready(function(){ 
    $('#form1').submit();
    });
    </script>
    <form action="page/site" id="form1" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
        <input type="submit" id="formButton" />
    </form>
```

You should use the form to submit that form, you tried it with submit button. it won't work.
use the form id, or select the form somehow and then call the `submit();` function. that's it.

You have another mistake in `<form method="post">` your code have postt, that is wrong.

Comment: I'm using Jquery 1.7 sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can call formButton.Click method on window onload method to submit the form 
And replace method= "postt" by "post"

```
$("#formButton").click();


<form action="page/site" method="post">
```

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.7.2

Comment: oh.. then you can use $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#form1").submit()
    });